# What does this command do ? mount -rw -o remount /

Tags: mount, password, root, reset

I have windows 7 and ubuntu 14 installed side by side on the machine
I've lost my root password, then I read this tutorial

http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/reset-lost-root-password-ubuntu-14-04/

on how to recover lost ubuntu root password but I did not understand what this command mean ?

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

I need to know that this command do and what is mounting/unmounting ?
I'm afraid it may cause any data loss for me ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you boot into recovery mode, the root partition (`/`) is mounted in read-only mode as to cause the least possible damage.

This command simply remounts it in read-write mode so that you can persist changes (eg a new password) to disk.

Without warranty or guarantee, I can say with 110% certainty that this will not hurt your data... But remember that you will be root when you're in recovery mode so just be careful *after* you've remounted the disk.